# A problem about transitive subgroups of $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

The problem is the following which was left by my lecturer:

> Let $n \geq 3$ be an integer. Assume that $G$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ which is transitive on $B=\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$. That is, for each pair $i, j$ of elements of $B$ there exists an element $g \in G$ such that $g(i)=j$.
> Let $K_i$ be the subgroup of $G$ that leaves each of the elements $1,2, \ldots, i$ fixed:
> $$
> K_i=\{g \in G: g(k)=k \quad \text { for } k=1,2, \ldots, i\}
> $$
> for $i=1,2, \ldots, n$. Prove that if $K_i \neq K_j$ for all pairs $i, j$ such that $i \neq j$ and $i<n-1$, then $G=S_n$.

Firstly, it is noted that $K_{i+1}$ is a subgroup of $K_i$, and there is an element $g_i$ that belongs to $K_i$ but does not belong to $K_{i+1}$ for $i=1,2, \ldots, n-2$. At this point, it seems possible to use $g_i$ to construct a sequence of left cosets of $K_{i+1}$ in $K_i$, but this fails because the transitivity of G does not work on the subgroup $K_i$ of $G$ since $K_i$ may not be transitive. So I can't continue to do it anymore.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K_{n-2} \ne K_{n-1}$ implies that $K_{n-2} = \langle (n-1,n) \rangle$ has order $2$ and acts as $S_2$ on the set $\{n-1,n\}$.

Now (if $n>2$) $K_{n-3} \ne K_{n-2}$ implies that $K_{n-3}$ acts as $S_3$ on $\{n-2,n-1,n\}$, etc.

Formally, using $i=2$ as the base case, prove by induction on $i$ that $K_{n-i}$ acts as $S_i$ on $\{n-i+1,\ldots,n\}$ for $i=2,3,\ldots,n$, where $K_0 = G$.

Note that for the base case we are using $K_i \ne K_j$ with $i = n-2$ and $j=n-1$, which the wording of the question allows. Also the assumption that $G$ is transitive is used to show that $G=K_0 \ne K_1$.

Comment: OP says $i<n-1$, so it starts from $K_{n-3}\neq K_{n-2}$?

Comment: @MathFail Although $i<n-1$, nothing prevents $j=n-1$.

Comment: Yes, and we definitely need the case $i=n-2$ and $j=n-1$ in order to exclude the possibility that $G=A_n$. Also note that the assumption that $G$ is transitive is used to prove that $G=K_0 \ne K_1$. The question is correct but the wording is confusingly convoluted.

Comment: By induction, base case is $K_{n-2}=S_2$, assume $K_{n-i}=S_i$, then show $K_{n-(i+1)}=S_{i+1}$, do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes that is the strategy that I am proposing!

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!